# List all UNC connected drives Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am attempting to list all remote and local drives on windows. Any drives mapped to a letter is a fairly trivial issue, using [GetLogicalDrives()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrives?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [GetDriveType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea).
The main issue comes with UNC paths, for example \\server\share\ while [GetDriveType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea) will work fine if I already know the path, discovering it with [GetLogicalDrives()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrives?redirectedfrom=MSDN) obviously doesn't work. I would also want to be able to find multiple shares under a single network location for example \\server\share1\ and \\server\share2\

I have tried messing around with windows api calls like [WNetGetNetworkInformation()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetnetworkinformationa) [WNetEnumResource()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetenumresourcea) and [WNetOpenEnum()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetopenenuma) without any real success, and I am unsure using these even gets the result that I am looking for.

The current (simplified) state of my code is:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
    DWORD mask = 1;
    for(UINT i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if(mask & drives) {
            CHAR driveName[] = {(CHAR)('A' + i), ':', '\\', 0};
            UINT driveType = GetDriveTypeA(driveName);
            std::cout << "Drive " << driveName << " is " << 
                (driveType == DRIVE_REMOTE ? "remote" : "local") << '\n';
        }
        mask <<= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help, or even an api call that might push me in the correct direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could parse the output of `net use`...

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, when I use `net use` it can only see network drives mapped to a letter. But any drive that is mapped directly with a UNC path it doesn't see. Am I perhaps using it incorrectly?

Comment: If I do `net use \\server\share` from the command line then `net use` sees it.  If you access a path such as `\\server\share\file` directly, it may not.

Comment: Yep, just did that and it showed up. But if I access the root through File Explorer it does not show up in net use with out calling net use on the drive. Guess I will keep searching. I found a github project called [quasaro drive](https://github.com/StieCon/quasaro-drive) it seems to implement some way of searching through them, it's written in C# so i'll have to do some translation. Hopefully it can show some winapi calls fingers crossed. But thanks for the help!